# Change Widget ID or Package Name for android/iOS platform on phonegap?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I have an app in Google Play with package `com.example001.android`and one app in the iOS store with the name `com.example001.ios`.

However, I am now using the [phonegap build](http://build.phonegap.com), have removed a lot of the bootstrap code, leaving only the `www` folder, I am using the widget id from `config.xml`, so now I only have 1 `config.xml`.

If I set the `widget id` to `com.example001.ios` I can't publish this app in android.  If I leave the `widget id` to `com.example001.android` I can't publish this app in apple store.

If I change the widget ID to a generic one, say `com.example001.mobile`, then I won't be able to upload the app to Google Play because the package name changes.

How do I set the package name/ID for each target platform?

Answer (score 27):

Try this:

```
<widget id="com.company.app" android-packageName="com.company.androidapp" ios-CFBundleIdentifier="com.company.iosapp" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

P.S. `android-packageName` & `ios-CFBundleIdentifier` property are not properly documented but its works tested on latest(4.1.2) cordova.

Comment: Thanks Aks! I have been looking all over for those properties but they are not found in the cordova docs.

Comment: @Charles have you tested it on pgbuild? i use cli 5.x with pgbuild and if i search in apk and ipa there is only the package com.company.app in the manifest files, no com.company.ios or com.company.android what is set in the widget tag. phonegap by itself says that they do not support different id's for differend os

Answer (score 0):

I would create two projects and have them share a `www` folder.

Here is an example for local CLI builds:

```
/MyProject_base
  /iOS
    /www -> /MyProject_base/www
  /Android
    /www -> /MyProject_base/www
  /www
```

The iOS and Android folders will each have a separate full project in them with the `www` as a symlink to the base `www`.

This way you can customize each project in regards to settings and keep one `www` folder between the two.

Here is an example for PGBuild:

```
/MyProject_base
  /iOS
     /www -> /MyProject_base/www
     /config.xml
  /Android
     /www -> /MyProject_base/www
     /config.xml
  /www
```

Create two separate `config.xml` use one `www` folder. You will have to upload each version separate and it will be two separate apps in PGBuild, but this will allow sharing one `www` with two different app namespaces.

Comment: I don't think this will work on build.phonegap though?

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize that you are using the Build service. I will update my answer shortly to include how I would do this for PGBuild.